# How to properly deallocate a Set of objects that inherit from SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, automatic-ref-counting

I'm wondering what the best way to deallocate the objects of a Set that inherit from SKSpriteNode. I have the following code:

```
class Raindrop : SKSpriteNode
{    
weak var barSpriteRef: SKSpriteNode?

init(scene: SKScene, barSprite: SKSpriteNode)
{
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "RainDrop")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: texture.size())

    barSpriteRef = barSprite

    self.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let width = scene.view!.frame.width

    let randomPos = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random()) % width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height + 50)

    self.position = randomPos
    self.zPosition = 1
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    scene.addChild(self)

    let moveDown = SKAction.moveToY(-UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height, duration: 8)
    self.runAction(moveDown)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func kill()
{
    self.removeAllActions()
    self.removeFromParent()
}
}
```

The function kill() is my attempt at deallocating, but it's not working as intended.

And I'm using a Set like so:

```
var raindrops = Set<Raindrop>()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to deallocate anything manually, ARC will do that for you when nothing is referencing the object.  Saying "it's not working as intended" is a useless statement when you haven't said what it's doing or what the intended behavior is.

Comment: You never remove the raindrop from the set, so it will not dealloc.  parent only applies to `SKNode`s,  does not apply to `Set`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How ARC does work

ARC does keep in memory the objects that are strongly referenced.

### SpriteKit

This is also true in `SpriteKit` infact every node strongly referenced by the `GameScene` (or referenced by a node reference by the `GameScene`...) is kept in memory.

### What your are doing is correct (but probably not enough)

You are trying to deallocate your `Raindrop` sprite using your `kill` method

```
func kill() {
    self.removeAllActions()
    self.removeFromParent()
}
```

This method does work **if** the current `Raindrop` is referenced only by it's parent and by some actions.

However if into another node you created a this `Set`

```
var raindrops = Set<Raindrop>()
```

and then added your sprite to the `Set`, you created another **strong reference** which will keep your `Raindrop` sprite in memory.

### Example

Let's define a GameScene and a Hero node.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    deinit { print("GameScene has been deallocated") }
}

class Hero: SKNode {
    deinit { print("Hero has been deallocated") }
}
```

> The `deinit` will print a message into the console as soon as the object is deallocated

Now let's look a this code

```
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
var hero: SKNode? = Hero()
var set = Set<SKNode>([hero!])
scene.addChild(Hero())
```

There are 3 strong references do the Hero object

1. from the `scene`
2. the `hero` variable
3. the `set` variable

Let's remove the first 2 references

```
hero?.removeFromParent()
hero = nil
```

Hero is still in memory because strongly reference by `set`.

Finally let's run

```
set.removeAll()
```

now we get the following message because Hero has finally been deallocated.

```
Hero has been deallocated
```

Comment: Do not forget about closures,  cyclical referencing could be occurring, not allowing the object to be referenced.